# Linking against GLEW with CMake

Tags: cmake, glew

My project depends on GLEW and is built with CMake, so i took the FindGLEW.cmake from here http://code.google.com/p/nvidia-texture-tools/source/browse/trunk/cmake/FindGLEW.cmake?r=96 and wrote `find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)` in my CMakeLists.txt. Problem is that i am working on a cluster PC were several versions of GLEW are available. One version is stored in `/usr/lib` which is not the latest. the latest version is stored in `/opt/local/lib64`. this is the version i want to link against. so i added the path to the FindGLEW.cmake under the GLEW_LIBRARY paths. the problem is that the makefile always links against the older version, but i need the newest version (1.7) for using stuff like `GL_PATCHES`, `GL_PATCH_PARAMETERS` and so on. can i some how force CMake to use the newer version like it is the case with FindBoost.cmake. one solution is to erase the older one's but this is not an option. i also changed the order of the paths in the GLEW_LIBRARY list, but without success.

in my old Makefile i just wrote `LDDFLAGS = -L/opt/local/lib64 -lGLEW` so the path is absolutely clear, but now with CMake i want to use the find feature, but want to prefer a specific version.

Answer (score 2):

I use this to link statically to a custom compiled GLEW lib at a specific location:

```
#GLEW libraries
add_library(glew_static STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(glew_static PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/ryan/DevLibrary/glew-1.9.0/lib/libGLEW.a)
target_link_libraries(smolder glew_static)
```

With this in place you can remove

```
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
```

You can use this with shared libraries as well, simply remove the STATIC keyword from add_library.

Comment: This is pretty unportable. Using find_package is much better.