# How do you add libraries to CMakeLists?

Tags: opengl, c++, linux, glew

After searching everywhere I could not find anything or anyone to help me figure out how to add **GL GLEW** and **SDL2** Libraries to my **CMakeLists.txt**. I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** and I installed the following libraries with

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev   #for SDL-2
sudo apt-get install libgl-dev     #for GL
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev   #for GLEW
```

This all worked great, and i was able to compile in g++ with this commmand

```
g++ ./main.cpp ./display.h ./display.cpp ./shader.cpp ./shader.h -l SDL2 -l GL -l GLEW
```

Now I need to switch to CMake Compiler and I have no clue how to add the libraries GL, GLEW, and SDL2 to the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linking against GLEW with CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958733/linking-against-glew-with-cmake)

Comment: There's [a whole wiki entry in the official documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries) about this subject, the instructions there are as clear as can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to include the libraries depends on a few things.  Some packages such as sdl2 have pkgconfig files that define the libraries and includes to use.

Cmake comes with a **FindPkgConfig** module that can get it for you.

For example:

```
include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)

target_link_libraries(executablename ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

You can also manually add them with the target_link_libraries function.

Other packages have "Find" modules like GLEW:  /usr/share/cmake-*/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake

CMake has lots of great docs in the man pages, and on their wiki as @Mikael Persson mentioned.

Comment: what do i replace the executablename with? SDL-2.h? nothing I try works? The wiki didnt help me much either. I know C++ but I dont know how to compile CMake with libraries.

Comment: The executable name is the name of the program you are ultimately building.  For example if you are compiling a program called "mygame", it would be "mygame".  You first have to define the executable using the add_executable() function.  For example yours might be **add_executable(mygame display.cpp shader.cpp)**

Comment: Sometimes simple examples are the best way to show you something.  Look at the link: [CMakeLists.txt](http://pastebin.com/qX9igTSS) for an example of a ver simple single-source program of mine that uses CMake.  Another good source for complex examples is to look at the source of the KDE project [KDE](http://www.kde.org)

Comment: Now I have SDL2 Working but for Glew and GL it doesnt seem to work. I have the lines `pkg_check_modules(GL REQUIRED gl)` and `pkg_check_modules(GLEW REQUIRED glew)`

Comment: GLEW doesn't have pkgconfig, but cmake has a `FindGLEW` module. All you need to do is `include(FindGLEW)`, and it will set the `${GLEW_LIBRARIES}` and `${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS}` variables